# Analizing accessibility for Android apps without its source code

Tags: android, accessibility

Please, I need analyze Android apps accessibility behavior for auditing purposes. That is, I don't have source code access so I need external methods to view his response. I tried some tools as Accessibility Insights, but they're clearly insufficient, so I want to try self made tools.
Anybody can tell me where start finding info about? Google Developers only had info about make accessible apps, but I need info about p.e. how Talkback discovers links, buttons, controls and so on.

Comment: You could [read about the Accessibility Scanner and the Accessibility Test Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/testing?hl=en#accessibility-scanner). You could [read about what sorts of API calls and events need to be raised for accessibility](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/custom-views), to see what sorts of things your tool could try to discover. And you could [read about creating an accessibility service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service), which your tool might need.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that's a lot to read